# When I search any record then after I click on print button it gives me error such as please select the row

Tags: c#, wpf, oledb

Here, I developed WPF application using a OLEDB (Access) database and rdlc report. Here, I have problem in Datagrid. THis application run perfect but when I search any record and it gives me error "Please select the record which you want to print !!!". When I debug this application I know about it . When I search any record that time checkbox value is set automatically false. So that's the problem. So please suggest me what i should do? May i change searching code or not and If i change it then please recommend me any good way. Thanks in Advance. Please see my delete button code because when i click on delete but then after it creates this problems.

Below Code is for Searching ChequeName :-

```
   private void txtChequeName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {           
       System.Windows.Controls.TextBox t = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)sender;
        string filter = t.Text.ToUpper();

        ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgDataArea.ItemsSource);

        if (filter == "")
            cv.Filter = null;
        else
        {
            cv.Filter = o =>
            {
                BankMaster p = o as BankMaster;
                //if (t.Name == "txtFirstName")
                //return (p.FirstName == filter);
                return (p.ChequeName.ToUpper().StartsWith(filter));
            };
        }
    }
```

This below code is for print data :-

```
       private void ImgPrint_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<BankMaster> bmlist = dgDataArea.ItemsSource as List<BankMaster>;

            if (bmlist != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in bmlist)
                {
                    if (item.CheckAll == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please select the record which you want to print !!!", "Error In Selecting Record", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ChequePrintReport chreport = new ChequePrintReport();

                        B_SQUARE_System.Core.Utility.GeneralDeclaration.isGridSelectionChange = true;
                        chreport.ChequeInfo__OnSaved += adddata_BankInfo_OnSaved;
                        chreport.isEditMode = true;
                        chreport.currentSelectedItem = bmlist;
                        chreport.ShowDialog();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
       }



                   private void Imgdelete_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<BankMaster> bmlist = dgDataArea.ItemsSource as List<BankMaster>;
            String msg = "Are you sure you want to delete selected rows ? ";
            int count = 0;

            if (bmlist != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in bmlist)
                {
                    if (item.CheckAll == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please select the record which you want to delete !!!", "Error In Selecting Record", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show(msg, "Delete Cheque Data", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                        {
                            foreach (var items in bmlist)
                            {
                                if (items.CheckAll == true)
                                {
                                    bmservices.deleteBankMasterInfo(items.Bank_ID);
                                    count++;
                                }
                            }
                            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("You deleted " + " " + count + " " + "rows.", "Total Deleted Row", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                            BankMaster_Loaded(sender, e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

[Application Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6BZ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your item.CheckAll condition inside your loops. You should not use the else statement here because all the items are not mostly checked-so the else code will run for some items.

Change the code inside the foreach loops like this:

```
            bool printed = false;    

            foreach (var item in bmlist)
            {
                if (item.CheckAll)
                {
                //Place the Printing code here
                    printed=true;                        
                }

                if (printed == false)
                {
                   //Place the Error message here
                }
            }
```

Change the delete code in similar way...

Comment: thanks bro. But I have problem in Checkbox selection. Single selection create problem. I attach my checkbox code in above question. Please help me